# Документация для open-source проекта

Tags: документация, php, yii, веб-программирование, opensource

Привет всем!

Написал небольшую библиотеку на PHP. Теперь встал вопрос о создании сайта  для нее. Сайт я решил делать с использованием Yii Framework. Ну и само собой разумеется, что на сайте должна быть документация по работе с этой библиотекой: использование, написание плагинов и прочее.

Вот хотел узнать, есть ли какие-нибудь готовые удобные системы по ведению документации. Основные требования - это:

- хранение всей документации в базе данных, а не в статичных HTML-файлах;
- наличие веток или версионности. Например, есть документация для версии библиотеки 1.0. Но в версии 1.1 добавились некоторые возможности, которых нет в 1.0. Мне бы хотелось не делать копию всей документации, а выбирать статьи, которые относятся только к определенным версиям;
- мультиязычность. Причем желательно, чтобы каждая отдельная статья, а не вся документация, имела разные переводы. Чтобы в случае отсутствия перевода, показывать оригинал статьи;
- подсветка или простое выделение кода.

Заранее спасибо.

P.S. В общем-то, все мои требования отражены на самом сайте [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.0/en/quickstart.installation): Только, как я понимаю, отдельных модулей и их исходников для создания такой документации самому нигде нет.

UPD:

Я думал, что таких систем видимо-невидимо в инете должно быть. А начал искать - не нашел. Может, у них какое-то название есть специальное и я не так ищу?

Comment: Почему не github / bitbucket? Код комментировать в стандарте [phpDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/), использование/примеры писать в MarkDown (да, в каждой ветке будет своя версия README.md), и в обоих хранилищах можно легко вести баг трекер и вики и принимать коммиты сторонних разработчиков. А может и благодарить их с помощью tip4commit : )

Comment: Вот MarkDown мне кажется удобным для нескольких примеров. А когда примеров уже становится больше десятка, то ориентироваться по ним уже становится сложнее. Нужна какая-та навигация. Ну и на будущее многоязычность не помешает.

Comment: Может быть, конечно, для моей библиотеки это излишне. Но даже если это так, то иметь под рукой такие инструменты и знать как ими пользоваться, никогда не плохо.

Comment: Вики, в-принципе, как вариант. Но хотелось бы, чтобы она была прям на моем сайте, а не на гитхабе.

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never

http://readthedocs.org/

- + Версионность
- + Многоязычность
- + Автобилд
- - Все располагается на чужих серверах, можно забрать себе проект с github, но там вряд ли будет подробнейшая документация по поддержке своего сервера
- + Можно тарнслировать на своем сайте с помощью простого DNS
- + Подсветка кода
- + Поиск

Answer (score 1):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpDocumentor - это отличный инструмент.

Он позволит Вам и документацию вести, и подсказки для IDE будут генерироваться, и поддержка версий есть.

Comment: Если я ошибаюсь, то поправьте меня, но я так понял, что он просто нагенерит мне кучу HTML-файлов. Для исходного кода это еще куда ни шло. А вот для обычных страниц с инструкциями: как писать плагины, как пользоваться библиотекой - уже не очень. Опять же, мне еще нужна многоязычность инструкций. Т.е. я вижу только один выход - хранение все в базе данных.

Comment: Нет, Вы не ошибаетесь. С разными версиями языка тут не особо. Тем не менее тег @example есть - чтоб писать примеры использования. Скорее всего, Вам действительно необходимо более редактируемое решение. 

P.S. В качестве совета: если Вы хотите большей популярности для своей библиотеки, задокументируйте ее PhpDoc, комьюнити это понравиться - подсказки в IDE никому не вредили.

Comment: Спасибо. PhpDoc я использую. Без этой штуки тяжело вообще что-то делать даже в IDE. Конечно, не везде у меня комментарии проставлены. Муторно их делать для всех методов и свойств :)
____

@Hawk, перечитал Ваш комментарий еще раз. А что Вы имеете в виду под разными версиями языка?

Comment: Имел ввиду документацию на разных языках (русский, английский,...) сорри что не понятно выразился.

Comment: @Hawk, все понятно :) Неужели самому придется писать то, что я хочу...